# How to Validate Form

Tags: c#, forms, button, c#-3.0

I have a windows form for a desktop app that has 7 fields,

how can I have the submit button disabled until the form validates?

I know I can validate the form when the user clicks the button, but if  i have the button disabled what is the best way to call my validation method?

Using C# express 2008.

Comment: Think your making it difficult for yourself @Alex. Why not just validate the form data when the submit button is clicked and if it fails cancel the submission and provide some feedback to the user why it cannot be submitted.

Comment: Its my homework assignment.
Just following directions to a tee.
although I do think that disabling the button until the fields are filled out correctly is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always call the validation method from the change event of all 7 controls. If you have bound the controls to some datasource the datasource shuld have an OnUpdated event.

```
private void TextBox1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Validate();
}

private void ComboBox2_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Validate();
}

private void Validate()
{
 if(ValidationOk())
 {
  Button1.Enabled = true;
 }
 else
 {
  Button1.Enabled = false;
 }

}
```

Or maybe:

```
private void Validate()
{
 Button1.Enabled = ValidationOk();
}
```

Comment: Button1.Enabled = false; will be executed everytimee?

Comment: @ Thanks magnus , That is what I am working on right now,
It's funny how peeps comment smack, but don't have there own answers.
You do have to add an else though right/
anyway now I have to get the validation method working properly.

Comment: Thanks, simple validation method and if true = button enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have googled it but there are plenty of article going on the inter-web. Let me see :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/validatingtextbox.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xht7x2.aspx

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/SimpleFormValidation.htm

I hope they help.

Comment: hmm. kind of but it really only shows for one field, and not how to connect all fields validation to the enabling of the button.]